# USB memory stick unmounts and vanishes

Tags: usb, memory, removable-storage

I bought this device a few days ago, and checked it with utility f3. It is ostensibly a Philips 256 memory stick, internally seen as an

Bus 002 Device 034: ID 090c:2000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)

It appears genuine.

Yesterday, I was in the middle of copying my video library onto it, when it fell over.

Now, whenever I insert it, it persists for a few minutes, and then vanishes. This happens both on my desktop and my laptop machines.

I extracted a section of my syslog<<

```
Apr 12 11:02:01 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1416.618362] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr 12 11:02:01 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1416.806360] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:02:01 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1416.898353] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr 12 11:02:01 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1417.098342] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr 12 11:02:01 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1417.206558] usb 2-1-port3: attempt power cycle
Apr 12 11:02:02 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1417.810315] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:02:02 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1418.234299] usb 2-1.3: device not accepting address 12, error -71
Apr 12 11:02:02 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1418.314298] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:02:03 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1418.734278] usb 2-1.3: device not accepting address 13, error -71
Apr 12 11:02:03 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1418.734392] usb 2-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.310743] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421164] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=2000, bcdDevice=11.00
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421167] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421169] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB DISK
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421170] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: SMI Corporation
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421172] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 09118403000342
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421701] usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1911.421898] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3"
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3"
Apr 12 11:10:15 LM-Desktop mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.560605] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMI      USB DISK         1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.561102] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.561619] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 487424000 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/232 GiB)
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.562258] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.562261] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.562894] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.590964]  sdc: sdc1
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.593618] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 1912.804028] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: Finished Clean the /media/roger/PHILIPS256 mount point.
Apr 12 11:10:17 LM-Desktop udisksd[809]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/roger/PHILIPS256 on behalf of uid 1000
Apr 12 11:11:50 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2006.228513] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:11:55 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2011.336844] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 12 11:12:11 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2026.953802] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 12 11:12:11 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2027.141821] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:12:11 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2027.233821] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr 12 11:12:11 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2027.433832] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr 12 11:12:12 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2027.621850] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:12:12 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.053879] usb 2-1.3: device not accepting address 14, error -71
Apr 12 11:12:12 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.133890] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.553911] usb 2-1.3: device not accepting address 14, error -71
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.554330] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 14
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570027] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2049 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570034] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570087] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 119812544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570092] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 119810496, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570126] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 223867520 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570129] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 223865472, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570131] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 223865473, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570133] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 223865474, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570134] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 223865475, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570136] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 223865476, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570181] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 233175936 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570183] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 233173888, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570185] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 233173889, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570187] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 233173890, lost async page write
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570220] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 233175941 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570242] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 233175938 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570253] FAT-fs (sdc1): unable to read inode block for updating (i_pos 3730782246)
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570280] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 233175938 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570288] FAT-fs (sdc1): unable to read inode block for updating (i_pos 3730782252)
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570353] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 244392128 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop kernel: [ 2028.570367] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 248685504 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop udisksd[809]: Cleaning up mount point /media/roger/PHILIPS256 (device 8:33 no longer exists)
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop systemd[1224]: media-roger-PHILIPS256.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: media-roger-PHILIPS256.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/roger/PHILIPS256 mount point...
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-roger-PHILIPS256.service: Succeeded.
Apr 12 11:12:13 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/roger/PHILIPS256 mount point.
.
.
.
Apr 12 12:04:10 LM-Desktop fwupd[6356]: 11:04:10:0643 FuEngine             device 602b0a6cc821d155208724f0e22f8d111542b74c [WDC WD10EZEX-60WN4A0] does not define a vendor-id!
Apr 12 12:04:10 LM-Desktop fwupd[6356]: 11:04:10:0651 FuEngine             device 2396250036142d895b79f25cc30512a624fc3d2e [WDC WD5000AAKX-004EA0] does not define a vendor-id!
Apr 12 12:04:10 LM-Desktop dbus-daemon[788]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Apr 12 12:04:10 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Apr 12 12:04:10 LM-Desktop fwupdmgr[6339]: Fetching metadata https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz
Apr 12 12:04:11 LM-Desktop fwupdmgr[6339]: Fetching signature https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc
Apr 12 12:04:11 LM-Desktop fwupdmgr[6339]: Successfully downloaded new metadata: 0 local devices supported
Apr 12 12:04:11 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Succeeded.
Apr 12 12:04:11 LM-Desktop systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.

>>
```

I suspect a file corrupted the device, but cannot delete anything. I would like to reformat it, but do not know how.

What should I try?

I am running Linux Mint 19.1. Is there any other information I might seek out?

Answer (score 0):

First, I thank telcoM who reformatted my file insert: I would appreciate knowing how to do this myself.

I managed to stop automount of the device, whereupon the device stopped unloading itself.
I then tried fdisk against the device, and deleting the only partition. Write failed, and the device unloaded.
I am returning the device to Amazon, as it now seems defective.